# popout browser windows still part of main page

Tags: javascript, html, browser

can browser popout windows be launched (like google talk conversation windows can be popped out into a new window from the main gmail page.) so they are still part of the main page i.e. share resources and access and modify each other, e.g. if the popout window contained a button it can be clicked and modify part of the original page without having to go to the server? I'm guessing the answer is no, but as I don't know for sure I thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the popout parent by using the `window.opener` property from within the 'popout' window. That will give you the `window` object of the parent.

So if on your main page you have a global variable `test`

```
var test = 'Hello';
```

It can be accessed from the child window using

```
window.opener.test
```

Comment: wow I didn't think that would be possible. so can a popout page script modify the parent page? i.e. `window.parent.test = "this string has been modified by a popout script";`

Comment: Yes as long as the popout is within the same domain, otherwise same-origin policies apply

Comment: I just tried running this in the console for a gtalk popout convo window. `var children = window.parent.document.body.childNodes;` but the nodes it picked up were those of the popout window itself and not the main gmail page. How come this didn't get the parent pages dom objects?